# How to get id from client?(express and mongoose)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I wrote a code to find the recipes base on the materials(this a object that i created before) but I wrote the object id in the code.
**I want client send me this id.**
how can i write my code in this way?

```
const express = require('express');
const { Recipe, validate } = require('../models/recipes');
const router = express.Router();


router.get('/',async(req,res)=>{
    const recipefound=await Recipe.find({materials:'62b703256f9ea31a51adde62'})//The object id
                                                 // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    res.send(recipefound);
    

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send the client ID from front end in request params. Example: http:yourdomain:port/route/:recipeID

In backend you can handle like this:

```
router.get('/',async(req,res)=>{
    const recipefound=await Recipe.find({materials: req.params.recipeID})

    res.send(recipefound);
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much. And do you know how I can send multiple IDs to the server?

Comment: You are most welcome. In this case, you can consider set these ID in the array form via req.body. For example: 
[
    {
        "id": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 2
    },
    {
        "id": 3
    }
]
Then you can get the req body via `req.body` in backend.